# Mark as read after accept friend's request

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, notifications

I have a simple function to accept a friend's request:

```
public function acceptFriend($id){
  $user = User::find($id);
  $sender = Auth::user();

  $sender->acceptFriendRequest($user);

  return redirect()->back();
}
```

It work's correctly but if other user send a friend's request, he send a notification. I want to mark as read it after accept request but I have a problem.I don't know how I can do query building to check this one notify. I know I can make a new function and like attirute use notify id but user of my website can accept request not only in notify list but in user's profile too.

I thought about read information form "data" column from "notifications" table but I have a problem. I try a few of query buildings:

```
$hello = auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->where('notifiable_id', Auth::user()->id)
                             ->where('data->arr->id', '12')->first();
```

or

```
$hello = auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->where('notifiable_id', Auth::user()->id)
                             ->where('data', '%12%')->first();
```

But it doesn;t works. "12" is id of sender,

The table structure is the normal notifications structure:

```
Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) { 
    $table->uuid('id')->primary(); 
    $table->string('type'); 
    $table->morphs('notifiable'); 
    $table->text('data'); 
    $table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable(); 
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

The data column will contain an array such as:

```
{
   "title":"Something",
   "arr":{
      "id":12,
      "name":"HelloWorld",
      "avatar":null
   }
}
```

Comment: What does the structure of your notifications table look like?

Comment: It's normal notifications strukture:
`Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->string('type');
            $table->morphs('notifiable');
            $table->text('data');
            $table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });`
Data contain array, like
`{"title":"Something","arr":{"id":12,"name":"HelloWorld","avatar":null}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the Query Builder equivalent of a LIKE query.

`->where('data', '%12%')` will generate SQL: `data = '%12%'` returning no results.

`->where('data', 'like', '%12%')` will generate SQL: `data like '%12%'` which should work.